# Debug Tomcat Web Application in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a Advanced Java Application(Spring+Hibernate) with Maven.  Project runs without any error.

I follow below process to test the application.

1. Build War using below command.
   `C:\Dev\ProjectApp> mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true`
   This builds war file inside target folder(`C:\Dev\ProjectApp\target`).
2. Place Application.war inside webapps folder(`C:\Apps\Apache\Jakarta\Tomcat6\webapps`)
3. run `startup.bat` from `Tomcat6\bin` folder.
4. hit the application in web Browser (`http://localhost:8080/`).

I want to debug this application from eclipse IDE itself. While application runs in webbrowser. I want to debug using breakpoints.

What are the steps to run this application in eclipse? What are constraints involved in this?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Please let me know if you need any more information to understand my question !

Comment: Do you need to verify the build cycle as well? Or just the flow of your application ?

Comment: Yes. maven plugin in already there. but just need to execute flow of application.

Answer (score 2):

To simply debug the flow of the application, you can use the eclipse as the basis.

Goto the `server` view and create a new tomcat server (or any server that you use for dev). Next right-click on your project --> run as --> run on server and select the server that you just created. Keep in mind that the server should have all the configurations that you need to have to run the application. If your project requires some custom settings in the application server, then tell eclipse to take control of the server installation by selecting "Use Tomcat installation". (double click on the server to configure it)

[image]

Next add debuggers and start the server from within eclipse.

Happy debugging !

Answer (score 1):

Set the environment variables first

`set JPDA_ADDRESS=8000`

`set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket`

You can edit the `startup.bat` to have

`call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%`
and start in the same way as above.

After this you can have your eclipse open a remote debugging session that connects to localhost:8000.

However, I would strongly recommend to use the WTP plugin in eclipse to build and start/stop the tomcat from within eclipse itself.